# Triggering another action inside ActionListener with JTextField

Tags: java, user-interface, switch-statement, actionlistener, textfield

So I have a GUI with a JTextField which is meant to first take user inputs for a "main menu", and once a menu command is entered perform a series of actions.  For example, in the following block, I take an action and use a switch/case to get what menu selection the user entered, but now i want to take additional inputs inside this action.  In the current code, the actionlistener will get stuck in an infinite loop because it doesn't wait for NEW input when I use ".getText()".  Is there a way to make this work (keeping in mind I need to parse each input for format)? Or is my understanding of ActionListener thoroughly flawed?
Here is a small snippet to give some context:

```
        @Override 
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

            while(command < 1 || command > 8){

                commandStr = textField.getText();
                try{
                    command = Integer.parseInt(commandStr);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Command!");
                    command = 0;
                }
            }

            switch(command){

                case(1): //Add new book
                    while(!BS.validateFormat(bookType, BS.IF_BT)){
                        textArea.setText("Enter the book type by number");
                        textArea.append("1: Book  2: Textbook  3: Workbook");
                        try{
                            bookType = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());

                        } catch(Exception e){}
                    }
```

Comment: By the way, this is my first time ever making a GUI in Java, so any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why dont you use a real JMenu or a JComboBox?
and having a content pane with the action specific stuff?
what you are doing is something of a command line interface with a GUI. Or use a JLable for the output and the JTextArea for the input

Comment: Honestly, the reason I'm not is because I have not learned the functionality of them and I was trying to use only the features that were actually taught by my professor, but if that is the easiest option I could look into it

Comment: okay... so why don't you use two text field? One with setEditable(false) for your text, and one with the input of the user? if you would stick to the text field only

Comment: Yes, that's what i have, except i use JTextArea for the outputs.  My problem is that when I want to take the next input, it uses whatever the user had in the textField from their previous input.

Comment: ah okay.. thats because us use the value direct in the switch case .. therefore the user has no "time" to enter something new. you need some kind of state machine (idle -> command selected -> value entered) so first time you enter the switch print out your text area text and store the current active command. when the user enters the new text,  action performed is called again. With the active command in mind you could execute the new input